# Cocos2dx reset or change environment variables for android in setup.py

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, environment-variables, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to just run a Hello World application using cocos2dx v3.4 written in c++. I installed the NDK, apache ant, and the android ADT. Unfortunately after running the build_native.py script in proj.android I concluded that I need the NDK v9 instead of 10. Also i need to change the directories for the SDK. I tried the following in Terminal

```
unset NDK_ROOT
unset ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
unset ANT_ROOT
```

Even after doing this and checking the environment to see if they are still there I run setup.py and it still says the variables are all set. Since I cant run the build_native.py script when I import a new project and the cocos2dx library it just crashes on startup.

Also when i run in eclipse I get an error saying:

```
[2015-05-12 21:37:40 - libcocos2dx] Could not find libcocos2dx.apk!
```

Comment: the `unset` command will only affect the current session in the terminal so if you want to change the paths permanently you should edit the files/settings depending on your OS. Then try to load the libcocos2dx to the new eclipse project and check if it builds, then you can try to go further.

Comment: oh ok, it builds but just crashes on launch. Would you know how to get rid of the environment variables for the terminal on mac OS X?

Comment: I think its same for Terminal as well as OS. Better you keep variables in bash_profile file Under "Current user" in "Users". It will always work fine. In case you need bash_profile, I'll send you mine.

Comment: How would you do it in either OS or Terminal. How would i get to my bash profile directory?

Comment: if you are using window the go to environment variable  edit NDK_ROOT varible path

Comment: if you using mac then ther is a .bash file which is hidden(but i donot know where you can find out) there u can change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to go about it on mac.

- on a terminal type vi `/Users/(ur computer name)/.bash_profile`
- press `i` (to edit in vim) on your keyboard and scroll the cursor to the variable you want to change
- after changing the variable to the desired file path, press `esc` key and type the following `:wq` in order (that is to save your changes in vim)
  you should be back to the normal terminal prompt by now and need to do one last thing.
- Type this on the prompt `source /Users/(ur computer name)/.bash_profile`

you should be fine by now, if you encounter any other problem feel free to ask in the comment below